# Testcafe's chrome takes multiple times to get same response from save server

Tags: angular, performance, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm trying to test my Angular application with Testcafe.

When visiting the website with chrome on my desktop, the performance was OK.

But when I tested the project with Testcafe (using chrome as well), the performance become very bad.

Here are the two images which I test with my chrome vs. Testcafe chrome

- [image: Using incognito chrome]
- [image: Using Testcafe chrome]

And the main differences

|  | Personnel chrome | Testcafe chrome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wating for server response | 291.55ms | 36.38s |
| Content download | 2.05s | 27.31ms |

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

I thought Testcafe was not working with some of the APIs, but seems like it's just much slower than the browser. I have tried Cypress which is also a testing framework but some of the functionalities are better in Testcafe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestCafe uses an internal web-proxy to process client scripts. Since your `main.js` file is quite large, this can lead to some slowdowns. You can find additional information on how TestCafe works in the following topics:

- https://testcafe.io/402636/faq?search#how-does-testcafe-work-if-it-doesnt-use-seleniumwebdriver
- https://testcafe.io/documentation/402631/why-testcafe#page-proxying

I would recommend you check TestCafe's new `proxyless` mode, which is being actively developed. It should help significantly reduce the test execution time. Please refer to the following article for details: https://testcafe.io/documentation/404237/guides/experimental-capabilities/proxyless-mode